# find largest numerical value in foreach Javascript?`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok take the following: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/3j4d8/)

how do i run a for each collecting the highest value for each of the north values and the lowest for the south in javascript?

Ok i went for this:

```
    function finder(cmp, arr, attr) {
       var val = arr[0][attr];
       for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
           val = cmp(val, arr[i][attr]);
       }
       return val;
   }
```

Comment: Give it a shot! PS: do you realize that what you're trying to do is **not** a reliable way to get the bounding box?

Comment: from that answer I'm guessing there isn't a defacto way to do it!

Comment: There are nice ways of doing that with, say, `Math.min`/`Math.max`

Comment: what algorithm have you tried so far?

Comment: none I came asking for a defacto way if any existed.. after @zerkms I'm going to try math min/max :D

Comment: Please note that you only have _Strings_, you should parse the numbers out of them too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has a lovely built in forEach function:

```
var lowestFound = false;
var lowest = 0;

angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
  if (value < lowest || lowestFound === false) {
    lowest = value;
    lowestFound = true;
  }
});

return lowest;
```

Not perfect, but it should work. :)

Comment: uuu thats a nice way of doing it!

Comment: You could also add similar code for the highest values in the same function (saving looping over everything twice). :)